# SQL to add zeros in front of existing data to meet field length

Tags: firebird

How to add zeros in front of existing data of NationalityCode field to make the length 5 ?

[image]

Comment: Concatenate `'00000'` and trimmed string representation of the numeric value. Get 5 chars from right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LPAD(nationalitycode, 5, '0')
FROM...
```

See https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-lpad.html

If you want to update nationalitycode:

```
UPDATE ...
    SET nationalitycode = LPAD(nationalitycode, 5, '0')
WHERE ...
```

Comment: an explanation, or sample output, or a link to the docs would help this be a better answer 

Comment: How can it be updated in the table ?

Comment: @Nukool, I've added an example of an update

Comment: More up-to-date documentation is [`LPAD`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-lpad)